# Installation of an agent when port is opened using ansible

Tags: ansible, port

I need to check if the ports are opened before installation with ansible. I have written playbook as below.

```
- name: Check all port numbers are opened
  wait_for:
    port: "{{ item }}"
    state: started    
  with_items:
    - "{{ agent_port }}"
    - "{{ service_port }}"
```

What needs to be done:
1. to continue to next step if the port is opened.
2. print a message that installation cannot happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*wait_for* will fail if any of the ports hasn't been started in *timeout*

```
- name: Check all port numbers are opened
  wait_for:
    port: "{{ item }}"
    state: started
    timeout: 5
    msg: "{{ item }} is not started. Installation cannot happen."
  with_items:
    - "{{ agent_port }}"
    - "{{ service_port }}"

- debug:
    msg: "Continue to next step ..."
```

---

For example the play below (with open ports 22 and 25)

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - wait_for:
        port: "{{ item }}"
        state: started
        timeout: 3
        msg: "{{ item }} is not started. Installation cannot happen."
      loop:
        - 22
        - 25
      # - 6566

    - debug:
        msg: Continue
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=22)
ok: [localhost] => (item=25)

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Continue"
```

, but will fail with closed port 6566

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=22)
ok: [localhost] => (item=25)
failed: [localhost] (item=6566) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "elapsed": 3, "item": 6566, "msg": "6566 is not started. Installation cannot happen."}
```

Comment: Works for me as expected. I've added an example. For your convenience available at [GitHub](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/blob/master/examples/example-110/wait_for_multiple.yml).

Answer (score 0):

this is not tested, but to give you an idea how you can use pre_tasks with tasks.. pre_tasks is a task which Ansible executes before executing any tasks

```
- name: Check all port numbers are opened
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Ensure {{ item }} port is opened
      wait_for:
        port: {{ item }}
        state: started
      with_items:
         - "{{ agent_port }}"
         - "{{ service_port }}"

  tasks:
     - name: actual installation tasks will come here.
       ----
       ----
       ----
```